# ImmutableJS fromJS() and Map() "ownerID" doesn't match

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, immutable.js, chai-immutable

I am using `chai-immutable` npm module for testing. Here is the test:

```
it("runs the test", () => {
    const initialState = Map();
    const entries = ["entry"];
    const nextState = setEntries(initialState, entries);

    expect(nextState).to.equal(fromJS({
        entries : ["entry"]
    }));
});
```

This is `setEntries` function

```
export function setEntries(state, entries) {
    return state.set("entries", List(entries));
}
```

The `npm test` fails:
[image]

What is this `ownerID`? 
How to fix the issue?

**EDIT:**

I have created and rewritten the whole file from scratch and it worked. It was exact same replica of the previous file.

*Still interested why it happened....*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you have this piece of code somewhere when invoking the test runner?

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';

chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```

typically you would use that in a file, say `test/test-config.js` and then call your runner like this: `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test-config.js --recursive`

(I'm assuming you need babel compiler, but the important part there is the **--require ./test/test-config.js**)

Comment: yes I do have this piece of code. I actually solved the problem: I created a new file and it was exactly the same. I have no idea why the new file worked well

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue with Immutable.is()

```
expect(is(
    nextStat,
    fromJS({entries : ["entry"]})
)).to.equal(true)
```